TIA circuit with reverse biases photodiode
Currently I created a TIA circuit with a reversed biased photodiode. I should be able to get a 30-300kHz signal, which is why the reverse biased photodiode. Reverse biasing the photodiode will namely decrease its capacitance and give a larger signal bandwidth. The current circuit should have a pm of about 45 deg and signal bandwidth of about 400kHz. The ADC needs a 0-3.3V range which is why I use the voltage dividers. I build the circuit, but it doesn't work. I am getting a output voltage of 0.6V instead of 1.6V. A vin+ of 1.7V instead of 3.4V. A non-inverting and inverting of 1.1V. Why does it not work?



Your OpAmp draws 8mA from VCC with no load which you are supplying through a 68k resistor.  Applying Ohm's law, V = 8mA*68kOhm, then you are trying to drop 544V from a 12V supply.  This is obviously not going to happen, so your opamp is unpowered.


Why does it not work?


DC supply voltage is too low: data sheet says minimum +Vcc is +5V for NE5532.
DC supply should be driven from a steady DC source: R4, R5 voltage divider is too weak.
Output pin #1 cannot drive your ADC to GND if -Vee (pin #4) is GND as well. Pin #4 should be supplied from a DC source more negative than -3V DC.

You might try substituting an op amp that has rail-to-rail output capability - but be careful of DC supply voltage - many rail-to-rail op amps want a DC supply of +5V or less.

DC supply of +5V or less is a feature, avoiding the possibility of damaging the ADC. Lately I've been using the ADA4805 for this kind of thing.

You're going to want to do it like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

C2 & C3 decouples the power rails for OA1.
Adjust R2 to set the transimpedance gain such that your max optical signal produces almost 3.3V on the output.
Adjust C1 for stability - cancels a zero on the input.

Reasons your circuit doesn't work properly:

Powering the amplifier with a voltage divider makes no sense - this is not how you would limit the output swing and makes the amplifier susceptible to noise and poor PSRR. Also, the impedance is way too high. You could at least decouple the divided node. You pretty much never want to power an opamp with an unbuffered voltage source. You could get by with another uniity-gain amplifier between the divider and the amplifier's supply input. But it would still be poor design and no reason to do that in your case.
Your R2 & R3 introduces a DC offset on the response because the non-inverting input is not referenced to ground (see your oscillogram). You could remove this offset in firmware. But why? It compromises the dynamic range and introduces another noise source. Again, this is a poor design. The non-inverting input should be ground referenced in your application.
The negative rail of the amplifier should be below ground. Even if you use rail-to-rail opamps, they are never truly "rail-to-rail". They get close (but non-linear) near the rails. this may be acceptable if you don't care about circuit performance at the lowest signal levels. A better design is still to use a decoupled bipolar power supply.


I assume the DC offset is intentional. If you don't have split supplies, you need it.

@JohnDoty If that is true, it's going to require relatively low value resistors to make a stiff divider. More heat generated and still worse performance. Or, an additional amplifier is going to be needed. But then you still have the reduced dynamic range problem with the inherent offset. That all might be fine - details are missing from the inquiry.

Why a stiff divider? Use a low voltage opamp powered from 3.3V.
